# Корректность условия задачи с английского

Tags: java

Не могу понять корректность условия что именно надо сделать. Помогите перевести правильно. Код писать не прошу, сам сделаю, но не до конца понимаю задание.

> File `in.properties` (pairs `key=value`) contains some sequence of lines. 
> Let the element with key indexi has the value `j` (`i=1..n, j=1..m` – natural numbers without leading zeros). It determines the index of an element with name valueij (`j = indexi`) you should work with.
>
> 1. Print the sum of values of elements, having the key `valueij` (see examples below).
> 2. Print the number of index elements with “errors” (`i, j` – unnatural numbers; no correct value-element for sum).
>
> The example of the file `in.properties`:

```
index1 = 3
value11=qw
value12=4
value13 = 5.1    
value14=2.7
index2=15
value21=
value22=
value23=
value24=k
value25=5
index3=1
value31=     3.14
value32=fgh
value33=5
index4=0
value41=
value42=e1
value43=2
value44=3
index5=b
value51=d
value52=e
```

**Output:**

```
sum = 8.24
error-lines = 3
```

Comment: Отформатируйте по строчкам, а то не понятно.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Файл `in.properties` (состоящий из пар `ключ=значение`) содержит несколько строк. Пусть элемент с ключом `indexi` имеет значение `j` (`i=1..n, j=1..m` - натуральные числа без ведущих нулей). Значение `j` соответствует индексу элемента `valueij`, именно эти элементы нас интересуют.

1. Найти сумму значений элементов `valueij`.
2. Найти кол-во индексирующих элементов с ошибками данных.

Т.е.: берем `index1`, его значение равно 3. Значит, ищем элемент `value13` и добавляем его значение к сумме. Потом `index2`, значение равно 15. Элемент `value215` не существует, увеличиваем счетчик ошибок. У `index3` значение 1, значит `value31` плюсуем в сумму. У `index4` значение равно 0, а у `index5` и вовсе `'a'`, следовательно они оба идут в ошибки.

Итого выходит:

- `сумма = 5.1 + 3.15 = 8.24`
- `ошибки = 3`

Comment: Спасибо, понятно

Comment: `добавочных нулей` -> `ведущих нулей` мне кажется лучшим переводом.

Comment: Да, пожалуй.